# Exploiting virtual-$Z_{\theta}$ corrections in QEC

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, resource-request, noise, ibm-quantum-devices

The [work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00858) done by IBM Researchers to perform virtual-$Z_{\theta}$ gates allowed them to:

1. achieving zero-time relative phase shifts;
2. correcting $Z_{\phi}$ errors occurring when applying some gates -- e.g. $X_{\pi/2}$.

From my understanding, the virtual-$Z_{\theta}$ gate is essentially a change of reference system, based on the knowledge of the occurred error.

Coming to my question: I wonder if there has been some attempt to define error correction schemes -- correcting $X$ noise as well -- which exploit virtual corrections to optimise resources usage -- in terms of qubit number and/or detections.